# How to get original image with cordova camera plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-camera

Previously (before cordova 5.0) there was ability to get original image from gallery by passing **DestinationType** to be **NATIVE_URI**. But currently we haven't this possibility. How to get original image with original size, extension, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FILE_URI but often it's much easier to simply handle the base64 version (unless you have specific requirements).